Fetch new messages while maintaining the ui view
so I am trying to write a chat app in swiftui. I'm using firestore as my database, and I'm trying to fetch more messages while maintaining the ui view. I want a ui update that looks like instagram's effect (https://youtube.com/shorts/ZBGCDmPy8CE, a loading circle then new messages show in the top of the current ui). But in my own app (https://youtu.be/EnemRxESOm4), when I fetch more messages, the ui will re-render then jump to the message that I want, which makes the user experience laggy. How do I make the effect that is same as instagram?
Also, is there a more elegent way to detect wether the user scrolls to the top of the vstack? I'm using ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey to keep monitor where the view is, which is annoying since I need to keep updating the variable.
These are my code:
struct chatview: View {
    @State private var scrollPosition: CGPoint = .zero
    @State var messages: [Int] = Array(1...30)
    @State var nextElement = 31
    @State var lastScrollPosition = 1
    @State private var lastAddElementTime: Date = Date()
    private let addElementInterval: TimeInterval = 3.0 // only update at most once every three seconds
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(messages.reversed(), id: \.self) { message in
                            Text("message \(message)")
                                .frame(height: 30)
                                .id(message)
                        }
                    }
                    .background(GeometryReader { geometry in
                        Color.clear
                            .preference(key: ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin)
                    })
                    .onPreferenceChange(ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self) { value in
                        self.scrollPosition = value
                        if self.scrollPosition.y > 0 {
                            let now = Date()
                            if now.timeIntervalSince(self.lastAddElementTime) >= self.addElementInterval {
                                self.lastAddElementTime = now
                                self.lastScrollPosition = messages.count
                                addElement()
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
                                    withAnimation {
                                        proxy.scrollTo(self.lastScrollPosition, anchor: .top)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        proxy.scrollTo(1, anchor: .bottom) // show the most recent message at the bottom
                    }
                }
            }
            .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
            .navigationTitle("Scroll offset: \(scrollPosition.y) \(scrollPosition.x)")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
    
    func addElement() { // add 10 messages in each update
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            self.messages.append(nextElement)
            nextElement += 1
        }
    }
}

struct ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGPoint = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGPoint, nextValue: () -> CGPoint) {
    }
}

Of course this is not my actual code, but they have the same concept.
I'm wondering is there a way that I can render the view and scroll in the background, then show the rendered ui on the screen. I asked ai, but none of their solutions solve the problem. Thank you guys!

I think it is better to use rotation here.
struct ChatView: View {
    @State private var isLoading = false
    @State private var messages: [Int] = Array(1...30)
    @State private var nextElement = 31

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if isLoading {
                    Text("Loading ... ")
                        .frame(height: 50)
                }
                ScrollView {
                    ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                        VStack {
                            ForEach(messages, id: \.self) { message in
                                Text("message \(message)")
                                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 180))
                                    .scaleEffect(x: -1.0, y: 1.0, anchor: .center)
                                    .frame(height: 30)
                                    .id(message)
                            }
                        }
                        .background(GeometryReader { geometry in
                            Color.clear
                                .preference(key: ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin)
                        })
                        .onPreferenceChange(ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self) { value in
                            didScroll(with: value)
                        }
                        .onAppear {
                            proxy.scrollTo(1, anchor: .bottom)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 180))
                .scaleEffect(x: -1.0, y: 1.0, anchor: .center)
            }
            .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }

    private func didScroll(with value: CGPoint) {
        guard !isLoading, value.y > 0 else {
            return
        }
        startLoading()
    }

    private func startLoading() {
        isLoading = true
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
            withAnimation {
                addElement()
                isLoading = false
            }
        }
    }

    private func addElement() { // add 20 messages in each update
        for _ in 0..<20 {
            messages.append(nextElement)
            nextElement += 1
        }
    }
}


wow! This really helped me a lot! I really appreciate your help. Using two rotation effect is genius!

Hey! Adding items to the top works great, but when adding items to the bottom, the view scrolls down automatically. Any way to fix this?
